# C# Linq one call to DB get multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq

Got this:

```
var ApprovalRoleRefList = db.ApprovalRoles.Select(x => x.ApprovalRoleName);
var CostDivisionRefList = db.CostDivisions.Select(x => x.CostDivisionName);
```

If I want this in one call to DB with linq, how would I do it?

This isn't what I want:

```
var lists = (from ar in db.ApprovalRoles select ar.ApprovalRoleName).Concat (
from cd in db.CostDivisions select cd.CostDivisionName);
```

In the project I got 3 more lists but is it "bad performance" to have 1 call or 5?
I know that this part won't be used that much but it's fun to optimize it.

Comment: Please show your `ApprovalRole` and `CostDivision` models. Do you have any relationship between them? A `join` would be good if there is a relation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get several lists of (unrelated types of) names in one query. This is usually a bad idea. Are you sure the extra hoops are worth it?

Comment: Have you tried using Union?  Note that the Linq Union operator is a distinct union, not "union all". See 101 Linq samples:  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Set-Operators-374f34fe#union1

Comment: @Jon, very good comment, I spoke to it the best I could! Hopefully I did it some justice.

Comment: Jon and Mike. I'll keep my 5 calls to the DB. I know that it doesn't metter if its 1 or 5 for the performance. But I acctually thought that 1 call to DB was better then 5 (even if it was litle). Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say that Jon made a very good point and I'm going to talk to that here. Clearly making more than one round-trip is more expensive than making five, but only at its simplist level. Further, it's not that this functionality is never needed either. Consider [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), which is used by Stack Overflow in fact, it has the functionality of performing exactly what you're looking for. So the fact that the functionality exists, tells me that even Stack Overflow needed to do this at one point.

However, before comparing ourselves to the needs of Stack Overflow, let's consider why Stack Overflow may have needed this functionality. [As of 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38263/what-is-the-total-number-of-hits-day-for-stack-overflow) they were getting about 1.5M hits a day. Well, when you're getting that many hits you need employ **a lot** of different techniques and making one round-trip is the ***least*** of those techniques. Extreme caching, load balancing, server farms, distributed computing, and the list goes on and on.

So in short, without fully understanding your application, I'm going to say that unless you fall into the boat of Stack Overflow where you're issuing millions of reads and writes per day, you are optimizing something that will literally produce no change. And thus, 5 round-trips is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you must return your results in one request, LINQ to SQL does support multiple resultsets from a stored proc. Take a look at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-to-return-Multiple-Results to see if that would meet your needs.